# Random selection of cards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi there super new to code, still learning about the basics. I have to create a Trading card game for my class and I am currently working on a dealing system. The player and the enemy both each have their own decks and 6 cards in each and I kinda know how I want to deal to them. I want to deal to them by changing the parent from PlayersDeck to Player and same for the enemy but each is only going to get 3 cards from their deck but I don't know where to start when it comes to telling the code to select a card out of the deck at random. So that's my question how do I tell the code to select a card at random. Thank you for your help. I'm coding in c# for unity btw.

Comment: I'd recommend finding tutorials about card games, or alternative forums. There are many examples of "card games" from which you could get inspiration. As it is, this kind of question is not fit for the "simple question & answers" format like Stack Overflow, and will probably be not well received here.

Comment: Add some code to your question so people can see what you have already tried. Focus on a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random number *k*, and then take the *kth* card from the deck.  If there are *n* cards in the deck you can generate *k* by writing:

```
int k = Random.Range(0, n);
```

See docs for [Random.Range](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any code and I didn't understand the part about changing the parent. But I will try to give you a basic idea about how can you approach this problem.

Let's say you have a list of cards as your deck called `deckList` and you want to pick a random card from it, then easy:

```
deckList[Random.Range(0, deckList.Count)]
```

However, you stated that you need to deal 3 cards from the deck which I assume you cannot pull the same card that you have already pulled. In such a case it would be best for you to get rid of the card that you've already taken out of the deck:

```
int index = Random.Range(0, deckList.Count);
GameObject card = deckList[index]; // The type of the variable may change
deckList.RemoveAt(index);
```

This code will randomly select an index, pick the card at that index and remove it from the deck. If you want three unique cards, you can loop through this three times, etc.